# Set date forms min attribute to todays date not working

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'm trying to create a form that will send some text and an attachement. This needs a date to be sent anytime after the day its created date, so todays date would be the minimum.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);
```

```html
<label for="datetosend"> Select the date you wish to send announcement</label>
<input type="date" name="datetosend" id="datefield" max="2021-12-31" min="">
```

But when I open this up the minimum date is not set?
What is the problem with my code?

Comment: just to make sure. You're running the javascript stuff after the page has loaded (or at least under the HTML stuff?). If not, try putting all of your JS code into a `window.onload = function() { //code here }` function

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console? Did you check for that before posting here?

Comment: Your code works in the snippet I created here.

Comment: It does seem like i'm getting alot of errors in the console. I did forget to check that before posting, but im still none the wiser.

Comment: Alot of errors are saying: TypeError: topFrame.browsingContent is null

Comment: Script in script elements runs when encountered, HTML loading and parsing essentially stops because the script might be adding more elements, including scripts. Put the script element at the bottom of the body, or wait for the [*load*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) or [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) events to run it.

Answer (score 1):

If we try to execute your code as-is in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zbj04Lm/), it works normally.

My assumption is that it's trying to set the attribute before the element rendered. Check this second [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zbj04Lm/1/) where I put the `script` tag inside the HTML. The code below doesn't work, because it's executing before the page properly loaded its elements.

```
<script>
  ...
  document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);
</script>
<label for="datetosend"> Select the date you wish to send announcement</label>
<input type="date" name="datetosend" id="datefield" max="2021-12-31" min="">
```

Review how your script and HTML codes are structured. It's a good practice to put these scripts required to run right after a page loads at the end of the `<body>` tag, or use an `onload` Event Listener.

Comment: I have my JS code in a seperate file. Then in the head of the html i call it using script src-....
Could this be the reason why?

Comment: @Fruitpencil That's a possibility. Try putting it at the end of the `<body>` tag just as a test, or wrapping it in an `onload` Event Listener.